# Output of weeknumbers in R and Excel is different

Tags: r

The ouput of Weekdays in R and Excel is different. Is there any way i can make both the ouput to be same. If possible the output of R should match with the Excel spread sheet.Below is the code and the data for reference:

```
structure(list(Pred_date = structure(c(7L, 8L, 10L, 2L, 9L, 14L, 
6L, 12L, 5L, 15L, 13L, 3L, 1L, 12L, 12L, 3L, 12L, 12L, 4L, 7L, 
9L, 11L, 11L), .Label = c("5/28/2020", "5/30/2020", "6/1/2020", 
"6/12/2020", "6/13/2020", "6/20/2020", "6/22/2020", "6/23/2020", 
"6/24/2020", "6/25/2020", "6/4/2020", "6/6/2020", "7/11/2020", 
"7/18/2020", "7/4/2020"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-23L))
library(lubridate)
date$Pred_date<-mdy(date$Pred_date)
date$Week_Act_Pay<-lubridate::week(ymd(date$Pred_date))
head(date)
```

This is the output in R:

[image]

Below is the output in excel:

[image]

Comment: How did you calculate week number in excel?

Comment: =WEEKNUM(A2) : this is the formula in excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation shows that the two functions (R's `week` and Excel's `WEEKNUM`) are calculating different things.

- **R**: [`lubridate::week`](https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/reference/week.html) Calculates the **number of 7-day periods** between the given date and Jan. 1st, *plus one*.
- **Excel**: [`WEEKNUM`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/weeknum-function-e5c43a03-b4ab-426c-b411-b18c13c75340): Calculates the **week number** such that the **week containing January 1 is the first week** of the year, and assumes that the week starts in Sunday. This is also known as "epi week" (short for epidemiological), or "CDC week". [Here is the reference](https://www.cmmcp.org/sites/cmmcp/files/uploads/spring_skeeter_06.pdf)

In R, you can get the epi week by simply using `lubridate::epiweek()` instead.

This example shows how each one is calculated for the date **January 13, 2020**

[image: Example of week and epiweek]

So, in your data, you can get the Excel results in R using:

```
date$Week_Act_Pay<-lubridate::week(ymd(date$Pred_date))
head(date)
```

Prints this:

```
   Pred_date Week_Act_Pay
1 2020-06-22           26
2 2020-06-23           26
3 2020-06-25           26
4 2020-05-30           22
5 2020-06-24           26
6 2020-07-18           29
```

Answer (score 2):

Excel's `WEEKNUM` function has starting day as "Sunday" and January 1 is the first week of the year. You can reproduce the same output using `"%U"` in `format` and adding 1 to it.

```
date$Week_Act_Pay <- as.integer(format(date$Pred_date, "%U")) + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Working with data from a year like 2023 requires an edit to Ronak's very helpful suggestion.

In years like 2023 that begin on a Sunday you don't want to add one to the week returned, because the first week of the year in that scenario will be coded as 1 and not 0 as in other years. Adding one in such a years makes every week off by one.

Here is a function that seems to match Excel's WEEKNUM well:

```
weekNumExcel <- function(dateVar = NULL) {
  sundayStartYears <- c(1956, 1961, 1967, 1978, 1984, 1989, 1995, 
                        2006, 2012, 2017, 2023, 2034, 2040)
  ifelse(format(dateVar, "%Y") %in% sundayStartYears,
         as.integer(format(dateVar, "%U")),
         as.integer(format(dateVar, "%U")) + 1)
}
```